# jpa native query retrieve multiple entities

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, sqlresultsetmapping

I have a database with 4 tables:

```
company,staff,department,project
```

**Company.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "COMPANY", entities = 
{
    @EntityResult(entityClass = Company.class),
    @EntityResult(entityClass = Staff.class)
})
...
```

**GetEntity.java**

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("GetEntityPU");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

String query = "SELECT * 
                FROM company c 
                JOIN staff s 
                ON c.ID = s.companyID";
Query q = em.createNativeQuery(query, "COMPANY");
List<Object[]> list = q.getResultList();
```

From above code, I can retrieve all data from Company entity and Staff entity.

Now I want to retrieve all data from any 2 tables:
maybe all data for company, staff tables **OR** all data for staff, department tables

How should I control every entity in my query? 
I really no ideas on how to do it.
Any ideas or useful source link are welcome.

Answer (score -1):

Mapping query to a bean could help you, check this out: [query to bean](http://mariemjabloun.blogspot.com.es/2014/05/jpa-mapping-native-query-to-bean-pojo.html)

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged, as the link can go dead at any moment. Give a small example of what should be done and then, if you like, add the link to give more info.