# jpa native query control entity(part 2)

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, sqlresultsetmapping

Cont. on [jpa native query retrieve multiple entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217569/jpa-native-query-retrieve-multiple-entities?lq=1)

- My database (testing) 
  [image]

  ```
  company - ID {PK}, name
  staff - ID{PK}, name, companyID{FK}
  department - ID{PK}, name, companyID{FK}, staffID{FK}
  project - ID{PK}, name, staffID{FK}
  ```
- First, I want to backup the `company` table.

  ```
  String query = "SELECT c.ID as companyid, c.name as companyname FROM company c";
  Query q = em.createNativeQuery(query, "MAPPING");
  List<CompanyDTO> list = q.getResultList();

  Company.java
  @SqlResultSetMapping(name = "MAPPING", classes = {
  @ConstructorResult(
      targetClass = CompanyDTO.class,
      columns = {
          @ColumnResult(name = "companyid"),
          @ColumnResult(name = "companyname")
      })
  })
  ...
  ```
- Second, I want to backup the `staff` table.

  ```
  String query = "SELECT s.ID as staffid, s.name as staffname, s.companyID as companyID 
                  FROM staff s JOIN company c ON c.ID = s.companyID";
  Query q = em.createNativeQuery(query, "MAPPING");
  List<CompanyDTO> list = q.getResultList();

  Company.java
  @SqlResultSetMapping(name = "MAPPING", classes = {
  @ConstructorResult(
      targetClass = CompanyDTO.class,
      columns = {
          @ColumnResult(name = "staffid"),
          @ColumnResult(name = "staffname"),
          @ColumnResult(name = "companyID")
      })
  })
  ...
  ```
- Now I don't want to fix my table and class. How do I control the ? from the following?

  ```
  SELECT ... FROM ? 
  List<?> list = q.getResultList();
  ```

  Any help please...

Comment: and does your JDBC driver support specifying the table in a SELECT via parameter? because not all do

Comment: Can you provide a simple example for me to understand?

Comment: understand what? You said you want to issue an SQL query like "SELECT ... FROM ?" so presumably want to put the table name as a JDBC parameter. And I asked, does your JDBC driver support that?

Comment: Yes. I was used mysql driver.